# PySpark Pandas UDF: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm' error

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Running a PySpark (Spark Version 2.4.6) job on Dataproc with the file structure outlined below:

```
dataproc
├── README.md
├── zipfolders.sh
├── src
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── jobs
│   │   └── myjob
│   │       └── __init__.py
│   │       └── Manager.py
│   │       └── Modelling.py
│   │       └── ExtractFeatures.py
│   │       └── Utility.py
│   ├── shared
│   │       └── __init__.py
│   │       └── ...
```

The `SparkSession` is created in the `main.py` file, and then is passed to the constructor in the `__init__.py` file in each job, and the following classes. ALL of functions called using this `SparkSession` are working as expected except for the `GROUP_MAP` UDF. Note: There is a scalar Pandas UDF, which IS working fine.

Anyway, so I have an `analyze` function in `__init__.py` that calls `Manager.py`. `Manger` then goes on to call `Utility.py`, `ExtractFeatures.py` and `Modelling.py`. Everything works fine, until I call an action on a dataframe in `Modelling`. I've used actions everywhere else for testing, and they work fine.

In my `Modelling` class, I am calling the following Pandas UDF and then using the `show()` action on it.

```
    def groupedUDF(self, data, grp_key):
        print("checkpoint???")
        schema = StructType([
            StructField("str_site_num", LongType(), True),
            StructField("artcl_num", LongType(), True),
            StructField("pe_val", DoubleType(),True)
        ])
        @pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
        def run_artcl_mdl(keys : list, df_artcl : pd.DataFrame):
            return pd.DataFrame({'str_site_num': 'testsite', 'artcl_num': 'testarticle', 'pe_val': 1.0}, index=[0])
        res_df = data.groupby(*grp_key).apply(run_artcl_mdl)
        res_df_cached = res_df.persist()
        return res_df_cached
```

Running a `show()` on the returned dataframe gives me the error.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'
```

I ran None assertions on the `SparkSession` before and after, and nothing returned an error. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Full log was too long to attach, but I called `printSchema()` right the `show()` on the SAME dateframe and that works fine.

Comment: there is a note in the documentation: If returning a new pandas.DataFrame constructed with a dictionary, it is recommended to explicitly index the columns by name to ensure the positions are correct, or alternatively use an OrderedDict.. In your case, you might do something like: `return pd.DataFrame({...}, columns=[..])` where the order of column names must match the return Schema of the pandas_udf function.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried that but I am still getting the same error. I actually think that the Pandas UDF is not being registered properly? I commented out the UDF I had written and added one that is a part of the documentation, and this is the error message I'm getting: `NameError: name 'normalize' is not defined`. Copied the example from [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.6/api/python/pyspark.sql.html).